# Managing notification in android notification tray

Tags: android, notifications

I am using notification builder to display the custom notification. My concept is to display the latest record in the database as notification and I have done that. And I am recalling the notification function every one hour so that if any newly added data will be pushed as notification. Now the notification once clicked should not be displayed again when that method is called every hour(if there is no newly added data). Any way to do this?

```
public void CustomNotification(String title_notify,String image_notify) {
    // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customnotification);

    // Set Notification Title
    String strtitle = title_notify;
    // Set Notification Text
    String strtext = "";

    // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification_ListView.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);

    intent.putExtra("location", location);
    intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
    intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
    intent.putExtra("country_id", country_id);
    // Open NotificationView.java Activity
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(image_notify);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            // Set Ticker Message  
            .setTicker("")
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            .setContent(remoteViews);

    // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imagenotileft,bitmap);
    //remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.drawable.androidhappy);

    // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,strtitle);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,strtext);

    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
```

Comment: What's preventing you from not showing the notification when the service is run every hour? It's as simple as not showing the notification when there is no new data every hour or I'm not not understanding what your are asking correctly.

Comment: When you click on notification at that time save one variable on `sharedpreference` 
and then check in notification function if this variable is set then not display the notification.